# Replacing range with variables syntax

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a dynamic range to sort my database and I am getting a type mismatch error on the last line of this code. I am guessing it is coming from where I replaced the values with variables. Anyone have any tips on how to fix the syntax?

```
Sub Fake_Code()
Dim Row_Limit2 As Long
Dim Row_Limit1 As Long
Dim Current_Sheet As String
Dim r As Range
Dim r2 As Range

    Cells.Find(What:="Title", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Name = "Range1"
            Set r = Range("Range1")
    Cells.Find(What:="Country", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Name = "Range2"
            Set r2 = Range("Range2")

Row_Limit1 = Worksheets(" Branded").Range("X:X").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Row_Limit2 = Worksheets(" Branded").Range("Y:Y").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

'I need to make all of the below dynamic based on the variables above

Worksheets(" Branded").Range("A1").Formula = "=COUNTIFS([" & r & "]: [" & r2 & "],RC2,R21C22:R71C22,R2C)"

End Sub
```

Comment: You're using `R1C1` style, so just change that line to `Worksheets(" Branded").Range("A1").FormulaR1C1`

Comment: @BruceWayne I am still getting the type mismatch error. I am also fine going completely away from R1C1 style. I am only doing it this way because I recorded a macro to get the basic part of the code.

Comment: You have a space in the worksheet name, is that the issue? `" Branded"` vs. `"Branded"`? (or perhaps the space in `"]: ["` should be `"]:["`?

Comment: The space in the worksheet name is actually part of the name of the worksheet because of the way I created the worksheet. I did fix the other space though. It is still flagging the error though.

Comment: try to use this: `Set r = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)) Set r2 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))`

Comment: when using the range object in the formula remember that the defualt of the range object is its value, not its address.  So change the `r` and `r2` to `r.Address(1,1,xlR1C1)` and `r2.Address(1,1,xlR1C1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line is building a formula but passing a range into it instead of just the address of the range, use `.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1`. Once that is there, remove the square parenthesis:-

```
Worksheets(" Branded").Range("A1").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & r.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ":" & r2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC2,R21C22:R71C22,R2C)"
```

It shows up as a `#value` but then we don't have the full data set to test with.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you and Scott. This worked perfectly. I am officially one step closer to finally being done with this code!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had made a mistake in the full line. With the above answer I figured out that it needs to be.

```
 Worksheets(" Branded").Range("A1").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & r.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC2, " & r2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",R2C)"
```